# XNA Loading models, not fbx

Tags: c#, xna

I want to load models from a game called 'Half Life' so I downloaded some from here: http://hl2.gamebanana.com/skins/122283, and i got this files: `metrocop_elite_normal.vtf`, `metrocop_sheet_normal.vtf`, and some more `.vtf` and `.vmt`. Can I load other files than `.fbx`? and how?

Comment: Normally you find can some converters that convert your models to .fbx (or .obj). Did you do some research on this topic on your own?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XNA 4: import FBX problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901709/xna-4-import-fbx-problem)